# Nagios, nginx and external commands - not authorized

Tags: monitoring, nagios

So we're going from Nagios 3 to Nagios 4, and as we've been a bit behind on our hosts, we wanted to do a fresh start.

The setup I went for was:

- Debian Jessie
- Nagios 4.1.1
- Lilac for configuration
- Nginx as the webserver

Now, I have everything working perfectly. The only thing I'm experiencing serious problems with, is external commands. I'm logged in as nagiosadmin:

```
External Command Interface 
Last Updated: Wed Dec 2 21:51:50 CET 2015
Nagios® Core™ 4.1.1 - www.nagios.org 
Logged in as nagiosadmin
```

However, I get this message:

> Sorry, but you are not authorized to commit the specified command.

My cgi.cfg:

```
physical_html_path=/usr/local/nagios/share
url_html_path=/nagios
use_authentication=1
default_user_name=nagiosadmin
authorized_for_system_information=nagiosadmin
authorized_for_system_commands=nagiosadmin
authorized_for_configuration_information=nagiosadmin
authorized_for_all_hosts=nagiosadmin
authorized_for_all_host_commands=nagiosadmin
authorized_for_all_services=nagiosadmin
authorized_for_all_service_commands=nagiosadmin
default_statusmap_layout=5
default_statuswrl_layout=4
refresh_rate=90
ping_syntax=/bin/ping -n -U -c 5 $HOSTADDRESS$
authorized_for_read_only=rlaugen
main_config_file=/usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg
```

Permissions are correct (or at least it looks like it for me) - "-rwxrwxr-x" on all cgi files, and owner is nagios:nagcmd. Members of nagcmd:

```
nagcmd:x:1001:nagios,www-data
```

I've tried making near any changes I can think of, but I'm still at a loss, and decided to try and see if anyone else had any idea on how I could resolve this. Let me know if any more info is needed.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you already have `check_external_commands=1` in nagios.cfg? Or if you have already followed this: https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/4/en/extcommands.html

Comment: Could you add more details please. Add the moment it is hard for me to reproduce the situation. For example, these commands were issued on the master, then these commands on the agent and this script has been configured on the agent and then the issue occurs. Please add a `steps to reproduce` section. Also, what external commands?

Comment: @bangal: Yes, check_external_commands is set to 1. Everything is set like the instructions in that link.

Comment: @Alfred: I'm running all the commands via the Nagios frontend. I followed http://www.tokiwinter.com/installing-nagios-under-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts/ to install Nagios. The config was exported from Lilac, and Nagios is reporting 0 warnings and 0 errors on the config files.

Comment: @rlweb, In my setup the permission looks like this: `prw-rw---- 1 nagios nagcmd  /usr/local/nagios/var/rw/nagios.cmd`. Can you please check if it works with this permission?

Comment: what command are you trying to run?

Comment: @bangal My permissions for the .cmd file is the same.

Comment: @keith force recheck of service / host

Comment: @rlweb, if you have not done it already, try `usermod -a -G nagcmd www-data` and also read the very end part of the documentation on command scheduling: http://www.tokiwinter.com/installing-nagios-under-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts/

Comment: @bangal Already done that, didn't help. nagcmd:x:1001:nagios,www-data, also added the line to the init file, but that made nagios throw errors because the .cmd file hadn't been created yet. I did however add www-data as owner of the rw folder, and permissions seems correct. prw-rw---- 1 nagios www-data 0 Dec  8 05:23 nagios.cmd

Comment: What is the output of "namei -mo /usr/local/nagios/var/rw/nagios.cmd"?  But this sounds like a websever issue and not an issue with Nagios.  Did you check your webserver access log and verify that it sees the 'nagiosadmin' user?  Do you have scripts and cookies allowed on your browser?